# Laravel Cron problems in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-8

I am trying to execute cron jobs on my Elastic Beanstalk environment but the .ebextensions script does not seem to be working.

This is the code I am using in the config file:

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    * * * * * root ./opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/laralog.log 2>&1

commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: I have tried to navigate to "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars" and this doesn't seem to exist on the server. Has this changed?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to search which files contain those `env` variables but for my current one is located `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env` so below provided my fullcode of the `cron-setup.config`.

```
files:
"/etc/cron.d/schedule_run":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        * * * * * root . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /scheduler.log 2>&1

commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

But I'm not sure whether is this the right way to do it when deploy to production. If anyone found this wrong please let me know. Thanks.